# Does transformation of basis vectors span V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow V$  and {$v_1,v_2 $} is the basis of $V$. Does it imply {$T(v_1), T(v_2)$} also span $V$? $V$ is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

No, consider the zero map $T:V\rightarrow V$ defined by $T(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$. Then $\text{im}(T)$ is the null subspace.

Comment: Could be useful to add that $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ span $V$ if and only if $T$ is invertible.

Comment: Actually it's sufficient to assume $T$ injective, because $$\text{dim}(V)=\text{dim}(\ker (T))+\text{dim}(\text{im}(T)).$$ If $T$ is injective, the kernel is the zero subspace and one has $$\text{dim}(V)=\text{dim}(\text{im}(T)),$$ and $\text{span}(T(v_1),T(v_2))=\text{im}(T)=V$.

Comment: is it true then that a subspace of V ,the image space, has the same dimesnion as that of V then Tv1 and Tv2 span V. i mean if Tv1 and Tv2 are basis of image space then can i say they span V

Comment: @raghu - Recall that a basis is a linearly independent spanning set, so if I understand your question correctly, the answer is yes. If $Tv_1$ and $Tv_2$ are a basis for the image then they span the image.

Comment: no not the image space the V itself?